# how can I add a translationFailSafe object if i18n is unable to loadPath specified in backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I would like to add a `failSafeLanguageMap` to my i18n instance in case the `backend.loadPath` is not found for example.

My current initialisation is as follows:

```js
i18n
    .use(I18NextBackend)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
      lng: langs.selectedLanguage,
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
      keySeparator: false,
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false,
      },
      react: {
        useSuspense: false,
      },
      backend: {
        loadPath: `some_path/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json`,
      }
    });
```

I would like to load `failSafeLanguageMap` from some json file as follows:

```
import failSafeLanguageMap from '/fail-safe.json';
```

and use this as a fail safe map in the case that `backend.loadPath` is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there was an answer that pointed me in the right direction, however it seems like it's been deleted since. So basically it requires the use of a [chained backend](https://www.i18next.com/how-to/caching). The chain backend is initialised as follows:

```js
i18n
    .use(I18NextBackend)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
      lng: langs.selectedLanguage,
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
      keySeparator: false,
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false,
      },
      react: {
        useSuspense: false,
      },
      backend: {
        backends: [
          I18NextBackend,
          resourcesToBackend((language, namespace, callback) => {
            callback(null, failSafeLanguageMap);
          })
        ],
        backendOptions: [{
          loadPath: `some_path/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json`,
        }]
      },
    });
```